# How to install multiple packages in conda from a file without creating a new environment?

Tags: python, package, installation, anaconda, conda

I took these from yml file of packages that my current environment is missing.  How do I just install these within my current environment?

```
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - appdirs=1.4.3=py36h28b3542_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_0
  - attrs=18.2.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - cffi=1.11.5=py36h6174b99_1
  - constantly=15.1.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - cryptography=2.3.1=py36hdbc3d79_0
  - freetype=2.9.1=hb4e5f40_0
  - html5lib=1.0.1=py36_0
  - idna=2.7=py36_0
  - incremental=17.5.0=py36_0
  - intel-openmp=2019.0=118
  - libgfortran=3.0.1=h93005f0_2
  - libxml2=2.9.4=0
  - libxslt=1.1.29=hc208041_6
  - lxml=4.1.1=py36h6c891f4_0
  - mkl=2019.0=118
  - mkl_fft=1.0.6=py36hb8a8100_0
  - mkl_random=1.0.1=py36h5d10147_1
  - numpy=1.15.3=py36h6a91979_0
  - numpy-base=1.15.3=py36h8a80b8c_0
  - pyasn1=0.4.4=py36h28b3542_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.2=py36_0
  - pycparser=2.19=py36_0
  - pyopenssl=18.0.0=py36_0
  - service_identity=17.0.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - twisted=17.5.0=py36_0
  - zope=1.0=py36_1
  - zope.interface=4.5.0=py36h1de35cc_0
  - pip:
    - absl-py==0.2.2
    - ete3==3.1.1
    - grpcio==1.12.1
```

Comment: Does `conda install --file` work?

Comment: (ß_env) jespinozlt-osx:install jespinoz$ conda install --file extra.txt

CondaValueError: could not parse '- defaults' in: extra.txt

Comment: What if you delete that section?

Comment: It still doesn't like it: `CondaValueError: could not parse '- appdirs=1.4.3=py36h28b3542_0' in: extra.txt`

Answer (score 9):

## Conda Env Update

If you have a YAML file, then the most efficacious way to apply it to a given env is with `conda env update`:

```
conda env update --file environment.yml
```

> ⚠️ **Warning**: The `conda env` commands don't prompt you to review and approve the transactions - it simply executes the changes. Be sure to carefully review the YAML file to ensure all of the changes are desired.

## Conda Install

The format that Conda accepts for `conda install --file` is that which matches the output of `conda list --export`.  It's not a YAML, but a simple text file with one package per line, similar to the one produced by `pip freeze`, except for the single equality sign ('=' rather than `==`).

**conda list --export**

```
appdirs=1.4.3=py36h28b3542_0
asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_0
...
zope=1.0=py36_1
zope.interface=4.5.0=py36h1de35cc_0
```

Note that the builds are not required, e.g., the following would also work and may actually be slightly more portable across architectures

```
appdirs=1.4.3
asn1crypto=0.24.0
...
zope=1.0
zope.interface=4.5.0
```

Unfortunately, `conda install` doesn't support PyPI packages; you'd have to install those separately via `pip install` in your activated env.

Comment: Note that even though `conda install` doesn't support PyPI packages, you can list PyPI packages within the environment.yml file. So by choosing the first method of using `conda env update` you can automatically have PyPI packages installed.